# Excel: match value from an array and return cell value from the same row

Tags: excel

I have some data in excel worksheet1 in this form:

```
person1 person2 person3 score
dave    sarah   jill    4
brandon hank            3
```

And in worksheet2 I have a column of people listed alphabetically, like this:

```
person  score
alex    
brandon 
dave    
hank    
jill    
sarah
```

I'd like to obtain each person's score from worksheet1 (with blanks for those who are absent):

```
person  score
alex    
brandon 3
dave    4
hank    3
jill    4
sarah   4
```

I've looked into functions like find, match, lookup, vlookup, but it seems like I will need something more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

1. Each person can only ever occur once in the source data
2. The source data occupies the range A1:D3 (with headers in row 1)
3. The first person's name for which you wish to return a result is in G2

then this formula in H2:

=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$C$3,G2),INDEX($D$2:$D$3,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$C$3=G2)*(ROW($A$2:$C$3)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$C$3))+1))),"")

Copy down to give equivalent results for names in H3, H4, etc.

Regards

Comment: Given your constraints, and **also** assuming the score is numeric, I think the following would work also:  =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$C$3,G2),SUMPRODUCT((G2=$A$2:$C$3)*$D$2:$D$3),"")

Comment: Yes. Good point. If that assumption holds then this is indeed a valid, and more succinct, solution. Nice.